# Adding a WPF form to a library in visual studio express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-express

I managed to create a WPF project, but for some reason, when instead I am in a library project and I try 'Add Item', then go to WPF, there is only one thing I can add, which is a user control.

I am not clear what a user control is, but clearly it has no 'Show' method.

If instead I tried copying the mainwindow from my WPF project to the library project, but then it would not compile (and I added missing references).

Am I doing something wrong, or is Visual Studio Express for Desktop just not featuring a WPF form?

EDIT: it seems I am after a WPF window instead (as per the Mainwindow : window class that gets generated when creating a new WPF app), not a form.

Comment: There is no form in WPF.

Comment: Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "form", that's an insult to my values and beliefs.

Comment: Not sure why you think every user control needs a 'show' method. A WPF user control's visual state depends completely on it's context. Example: what is the parent control and it's display properties? Nonetheless, user controls such as `Window` do have `Show()`. So, if you want a window, simply change the base class of your `UserControl` to a `Window` in both the .xaml file and in the .xaml.cs file.